# Type constant in c#?

Tags: c#, constants

Is there an equivalent to this in C#?

```
#define TypeConstant int

int main()
{
        TypeConstant x = 5;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Edit: I am not sure how this is related to defining a regular constant, I have explicitly written type constant, not a constant value! Read before you vote guys!

Comment: C# doesn't implement a *full* precompiler, besides the `#if`, there are no structures to control the source code that is feeded to the compiler. So no macro's as well.

Comment: @Alejandro, although the correct answer exists in that question, I wasn't exactly looking for `typedef` but apparently, that's the way.

Answer (score 5):

It's not exactly the same, but types can be aliased by using the [using Directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx):

```
using TypeConstant = System.Int32;
```

As Kyle points out in the comments, you need to use the full type name here (e.g. `System.Int32`) instead of the C# aliases (e.g. `int`).

Comment: Yes, but that's not a precompiler directive, neither can you override it in the middle of a source file.

Comment: @CommuSoft: That's true, but he did not mention that any of these were a requirement. In fact, since he calls them "type constants", I seriously doubt that he *wants* to change them in the middle of a source file.

Comment: You might also want to explicitly mention that you can't use the C# keyword aliases for types.  I.e. `using TypeConstant = int;` wouldn't work.  You have to use the full type name (as you did in your answer).

Comment: @Kyle: Good point, done!